# Copy Database error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Trying to "Copy Database" from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2012 through SSMS. It fails, and destination server's event log says

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

**Edit Nov. 24, 2016**
Tried Copying from SQL Server 2016 to another SQL Server 2016 and got same error.

Comment: Are the table definitions identical? If you are copying individual columns from multiple tables to individual columns in multiple tables, are the column definitions identical? Is there a chance you could provide us with a copy of the table/column definitions? Thanks.

Comment: Has the database compatibility level been set to a lower level? Are the Editions the same? (Enterprise, Standard, ...)

Comment: I am trying this simply within the same server instance [2016], just updating the name.  With the intention of making myself a simple user training database.  I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

> "Trying to "Copy Database" from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2012
>   through SSMS."

You cannot copy a database from a 'higher' version (2016) of Sql Server to a 'lower' version of Sql Server (2012).  That's called 'downgrading' and it not supported.  There are numerous Internet posts on 'options' (like scripting individual objects, etc.) for doing this type of activity.

**UPDATE 2/11/2017**

There is an [open connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2892491) that appears to be addressing the same problem you're having

Comment: Is OP probably asking about data export and data import? This is possible over different versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @hot2use - I took 'Copy Database' as just that.

Comment: @hot2use I was talking about the 3rd option. In SSMS, below Tasks > Import Data, and Tasks > Export Data, 3rd option is Copy Database

Comment: @ScottHodgin Wonder why the error message doesn't say just that "Downgrading not supported". Would've saved me some time :)

Comment: My guess is, your down-level instance just doesn't 'understand' something that is in your 'up-level' database - it just says something is wrong.   All kinds of things change between Sql Server versions.

Comment: From this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx) - A database cannot be moved or copied to an earlier version of SQL Server.

Comment: @ScottHodgin unmarking as answer because today I tried copying database from one SQL Server 2016 to another, and got the same error. The source server database in turn was copied from another SQL Server 2012 (down-to-up).

Comment: I get this error trying to clone a SQL Server 2016 db, i.e., create a copy of the db and all its data on the same SQL Server instance.Since the source and destination servers are the same, upgrade/downgrade can't be the issue. I can provide the stack trace if it's helpful, but it won't fit in a comment, and it's not an answer.

Comment: That error happens using the SQL Management Object method. I get a different low-level error with detach and attach, won't report it here, different topic.